# Override function in a module with complex file tree

Tags: python, module

I have a module `module` containing 2 functions `a` and `b` splited into 2 different files `m1.py` and `m2.py`.

The module's file tree:

```
module/
    __init__.py
    m1.py
    m2.py
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from .m1 import a
from .m2 import b
```

`m1.py` contains:

```
def a():
    print('a')
```

`m2.py` contains:

```
from . import a

def b():
   a()
```

Now, I want to override the function `a` in a `main.py` file, such that the function `b` uses the new function `a`. I tried the following:

```
import module

module.a = lambda: print('c')
module.b()
```

But it doesn't work, `module.b()` still print `a`.

Comment: Why not use inheritance?

Comment: I don't see what you mean?

Comment: Make a parent class with all your functions, Make a child class inheriting from that parent class overriding the functions you want overriden

Comment: Okay, I see. But, it doesn't make sense to do this in this case because these functions `a` and `b` share nothing in common.

Comment: But that will make your life easier in the longer run perhaps but let me see why this isn’t working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, that consists in not importing with `from . import a` but with `import module`.

`m2.py` becomes:

```
import module

def b():
    module.a()
```

Comment: Great, but I would suggest still sticking with either classes, or using the same file for functions you want to override for cleaner code